# How to show an error message after an input/field

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to do a check without vuevalidate. I just need to show this message below the input/field when I get an error or false.

I tried using `:error-messages`. But it returns me an error

Error: `check failed for prop "errorMessages". Expected String, Array, got Function`

Code

```
<v-text-field
   class="ma-0 pa-0"
   v-model="timeStart"
   :counter="5"
   :rules="rules_time"
   label="Hora de início"
   @blur="verificarHora"
   :error-messages="messageErrors"
></v-text-field>

...
methos: {
...
verificarHora(element){
      if(!element.target.value.match(/^[0-9]+$/)){
        this.messageErrors()
      }
},
messageErrors(){
      return 'erro';
},
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually accomplish this behaviour in Vuetify by adding the `rules` parameter (see more [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-text-field/#props)).

So, as an example, if your input value is not allowed to exceed 20 characters and only letters are allowed, you could write the following code:

```
<template>
  <v-text-field
    counter="20"
    :rules="myRules"
  />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  ...
  data: () => ({
    myRules: [
      input => input.length <= 20 || "Input exceeds 20 characters.",
      input => /^[A-Za-zäÄöÖüÜß]*$/.test(input) || "Only letters are allowed."
    ]
  })
  ...
}
</script>
```